# What is the difference between `MaybeUninit::<[MaybeUninit<T>; N]>::uninit().assume_init()` and `[MaybeUninit<T>::uninit(); N]`?

Tags: rust, initialization, maybeuninit

The Rust documentation for [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initializing-an-array-element-by-element) explain that an  array should be initialized with...

```rust
let mut array: [MaybeUninit<T>; N] = unsafe { MaybeUninit::<[MaybeUninit<T>; N]>::uninit().assume_init() };
```

However, could I not just initialize the array with...

```rust
let mut array: [MaybeUninit<T>; N] = [MaybeUninit<T>::uninit(); N];
```

I created [a reproduction in Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KGTdYf3xc) and I could not see any difference between these two examples.

I did find [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/96274) which appears to imply there may have been a difference between these two examples in the past. However, it appears that this has now been fixed?

*So, is there a difference between these two examples? Why does the documentation recommend the first, when the second is more concise and easier to understand? Should the documentation be updated?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... I wrote this question and just before I published it, I figured it out!

When `T` does implement `Copy`, then `[MaybeUninit<T>::uninit(); N]` is valid, as `impl<T> Copy for MaybeUninit<T> where T: Copy`. However, when `T` does not implement `Copy`, then it does not work. In that case, you are required to use `unsafe { MaybeUninit::<[MaybeUninit<T>; N]>::uninit().assume_init() }` instead.

From the Rust documentation for an [`array`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html)...

> A repeat expression `[expr; N]` where `N` is how many times to repeat `expr` in the array. expr must either be:
>
> - A value of a type implementing the Copy trait,
> - A const value.

However, this also explains why in the documentation for [`MaybeUninit::uninit_array`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#method.uninit_array) it mentions that...

> Note: in a future Rust version this method may become unnecessary when Rust allows inline const expressions. The example below could then use `let mut buf = [const { MaybeUninit::<u8>::uninit() }; 32];`.

Comment: As a note: If you are looking to avoid `unsafe` then I would recommend the use of `std::array::from_fn`, which is pretty concise. And since `MaybeUninit::uninit` is `const` and doesn't do anything really, I would be a bit surprised if the compiler couldn't evaluate `from_fn` at compile-time.

Comment: @PatientPenguin: The compiler can only evaluate `const fn`s at compile-time, and `std::array::from_fn` is not one.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I was under the impression that `const` guarantees that a function is evaluated at compile time, though it is not a requirement for it. The compiler is free to, if it determines it is possible, evaluate a non-const function at compile time.

Comment: @PatientPenguin You _are_ mistaken: you are correct that being `const` is not a requirement for evaluating at compile-time, but you're wrong that `const` guarantees compile time evaluation. It does not. Moreover, most of the times it will never do that, almost guaranteed _not_ to do that. It is like `constexpr` in C++, not like `consteval`.

Comment: @PatientPenguin But since the very motivation for using `MaybeUninit` is performance (if you don't care about it you can just use the safe `Option`), I would not suggest `array::from_fn()` which tends to optimize poorly with checking that it optimizes well. Though, it looks like it does.

Comment: Huh. Thank you for the correction and  information @ChayimFriedman!